# CONFLICT_IGNORE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

I am currently working on an app involving the SQLite database, and I have a problem in the insertOrIgnore(ContentValues values) method. I have created a helper class (separate .java file), and in the aforementioned method have defined

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

After that line, I have a try/finally block in which I have the following statement:

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

I am using Eclipse and it underlines just the CONFLICT_IGNORE part, stating "CONFLICT_IGNORE cannot be resolved or is not a field".

What could possibly be wrong whit this? I have run out of options and things to try. These are my imports in that file:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant was introduced in api level 8 (Froyo). Does your application has min sdk set to froyo?

Comment: No, it is set to 4. I am doing everything step by step as explained in a tutorial, and they have set it to 4 as well. I thought it might had something to do with the versions of the SDK, Eclipse or something in my environment that might differ from their, but I would have never considered this because I assume it works that way for the one who wrote the tutorial. I have corrected this and it isn't displayed as an error anymore. Thank you so much!